# Lite empty on return from function in python

Tags: python

Question is why is the variable test empty? The program will return the correctly sorted array. But it does not get assigned it seems.

```
def my_sort(array_to_sort):
    sort = False
    number_of_items = len(array_to_sort)
    print "sorted array: ", array_to_sort

    for i in range(0, number_of_items-1):
        if array_to_sort[i] > array_to_sort[i+1]:
            tmp = array_to_sort[i]
            array_to_sort[i] = array_to_sort[i+1]
            array_to_sort[i+1] = tmp
            sort = True
    if sort == True:
        my_sort(array_to_sort)
    elif sort == False:
        return array_to_sort

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()

    arr = [4,5,7,3,2,1]
    test = my_sort(arr)
    print (test)
```

This will return the following.

```
sorted array:  [4, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1]
sorted array:  [4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 7]
sorted array:  [4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 7]
sorted array:  [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7]
sorted array:  [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
sorted array:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
None
```

Comment: I have answered your question, but could you tell me, what are you trying to do with this sorting function of yours?

Comment: I am just doing a simple sort. Just testing out the language so nothing very serious. I know I could just use .sort() to do it.

Comment: Good thing about python is that you don't have to bother yourself with the little things, there's a library for most of what you can imagine. Sorting, serializing, parsing and many more are among them.

Comment: Agreed, I kind of like it. But being used to JAVA it seems kind of odd to not needing to define the variables.

Comment: I've come to Python from Delphi background and I never missed defining variables :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot return in your first condition:

```
if sort == True:
    return my_sort(array_to_sort)
```

also you don't need to compare boolean value to a boolean value. Your code should look like this:

```
def my_sort(array_to_sort):
    sort = False
    number_of_items = len(array_to_sort)
    print "sorted array: ", array_to_sort

    for i in range(0, number_of_items-1):
        if array_to_sort[i] > array_to_sort[i+1]:
            tmp = array_to_sort[i]
            array_to_sort[i] = array_to_sort[i+1]
            array_to_sort[i+1] = tmp
            sort = True
    if sort:
        return my_sort(array_to_sort)
    else:
        return array_to_sort

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()

    arr = [4,5,7,3,2,1]
    test = my_sort(arr)
    print (test)
```

Comment: I'd tried the code also adding with your logic.But can tell logic behind that? cause it still return Null.

Comment: Yeah now i got what you want to say. +1 from my side.